# Bucket size in tbf

Tags: linux, tc, qos

I've read many times about [Linux's token bucket filter (tbf)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tc-tbf) and still I don't fully understand how I should calculate the `burst` and `latency` parameters, shame on me :(

I suppose that a reasonable latency is around 50 ms. OK, but what value should burst take?

The manpage says:

> The latter calculation takes into account the size of  the  bucket,
>   the  rate and possibly the peakrate (if set). These two parameters are
>   mutually exclusive.

So, how is latency related to bucket and filter? Is there a formula to calculate it? Or is it simply a matter of, "OK, X bytes of burst and Y seconds of latency is good for me"?

Comment: To everyone finding this unclear: `tbf` is part of the Linux traffic control framework. `man tbf` or `man tc-tbf` ought to bring up documentation.

Comment: From your edit, it sounds like you need an explanation of what a token bucket filter is, conceptually. I'll add one in to my answer once I'm back in front of a computer (writing this on my phone.)

Comment: Finally added in the conceptual explanation

Answer (score 20):

From the manpage, the only constraint on `burst` is that it must be high enough to allow your configured rate: it must be at least rate / HZ. HZ is a kernel configuration parameter; you can figure out what it is on your system by checking your kernel config. E.g., on Debian, you can:

```
$ egrep '^CONFIG_HZ_[0-9]+' /boot/config-`uname -r`
CONFIG_HZ_250=y
```

so HZ on my system is 250. To hit a rate of 10mbps, I'd thus need a `burst` of at least 10,000,000 bits/sec ÷ 250 Hz = 40,000 bits = 5000 bytes. (Note the higher value in the manpage is from when HZ=100 was the default).

But beyond this, `burst` is also a policy tool. It configures the extent to which you can use less bandwidth now to "save" it for future use. One common thing here is that you may want to allow small downloads (say, a web page) to go very fast, while throttling big downloads. You do this by increasing `burst` to the size you consider a small download. (Though, you'd often switch to a classfull qdisc like htb, so you can segment out the different traffic types.)

So: you configure burst to be at least large enough to achieve the desired `rate`. Beyond that, you may increase it further, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

## Conceptual Model of a Token Bucket Filter

[image: Token Bucket Filter]

A "bucket" is a metaphorical object. Its key properties are that it can hold tokens, and that the number of tokens it can hold is limited—if you attempt to add more, it "overflows" and the extra tokens are lost (just like trying to put too much water in an actual bucket). The size of the bucket is called `burst`.

In order to actually transmit a packet onto the network, that packet must obtain tokens equal to its size in bytes or `mpu` (whichever is larger).

There is (or can be) a line (queue) of packets waiting for tokens. This occurs when the bucket is empty, or alternatively has fewer tokens than the size of the packet. There is only so much room on the sidewalk in front of the bucket, and the amount of room (in bytes) is set directly by `limit`. Alternatively, it can be set indirectly with `latency` (in an ideal world, the calculation would be `rate`×`latency`).

When the kernel wants to send a packet out the filtered interface, it attempts to place the packet at the end of the line. If there isn't any room on the sidewalk, that's unfortunate for the packet, because at the end of the sidewalk is a bottomless pit, and the kernel drops the packet.

The final piece is a token-making machine that adds `rate`/`HZ` tokens to the bucket every tick. (This is why your bucket must be at least this large, otherwise some of the newly-minted tokens will be immediately discarded).

Comment: I thought that burst it's the opposite, that you allow surpass the rate for a moment, that were compensated by a lower rate later to reach the average rate...

Comment: @sebelk I'm not sure without RTFS, but it'd work out to the same result, except for the case when tbf is added to an interface that is currently running above the `rate`. Or not, as you could just say the bucket starts full...

Comment: @sebelk: That is also true. Lets say we have a bucket of 1000 bytes (burst size) and the token rate is 10 bytes pr. second. So if no packets have arrived for 100 seconds the bucket will be filled. Then the next 1000 bytes of packets that arrive will be transmitted immediately without being queued, aka. a burst in the data rate which can be above the rate of token creation.

Answer (score 10):

Another answer to complement derobert's.

Firstly on modern Intel CPU's the manual is out of date.  Modern CPU's have high resolution timers, and modern Linux is tick less - literally meaning there are no timer ticks.  Thus all those comments making buckets big enough to hold the tokens in one timer are irrelevant. In fact the bucket analogy was only there to help the user understand the interaction between the timer granularity and send speed.  Now that Linux has nanosecond timers on modern hardware it loses it's usefulness.

For TBF the *burst* parameter is the number of bytes that can be sent at unlimited speed before the rate limiting (specified by *rate*) kicks in.  Once rate limiting has kicked in the only way to burst again is to limit your sending to below that rate.

For example, lets say your tbf *burst* parameter is 10K bytes, and your tbf *rate* parameter is 2K bytes/second, and you are currently rate limited (ie the burst is exhausted, so you are limited to sending at 2kbps).  If you voluntarily reduced the speed you sending at to 1Kbps for 10 seconds, you would accumulate your 10K bytes burst allowance back again (= (2000 [bytes/sec] - 1000 [bytes/sec]) * 10 sec).  Keeping it below 1kbps for more than 10sec would have no effect because tbf does not allow you are not allowed to accumulate more than the *burst* parameter.

If you stopped spending entirely then you would get your burst allowance back again in 5sec (= 100000 [bytes] / 2000 [bytes/sec]).

You don't have to get all your burst allowance back to use it, you can use as much as you have accumulated.

Another way of looking at this is: you are allowed to send *burst* bytes at unlimited speed, thereafter your long term average speed can never exceed *rate*.  However, because it is a long term average, if you drop below *rate* you are allowed to catch up by sending at full speed - but even then you are only allowed to send at full for at most *burst* bytes (and if that doesn't allow you to catch up you can't).

The other wrinkle is TBF has **two** of these rate limiters, and your traffic has to pass through both.  In the second one, the burst parameter is called *mtu* and, and the rate is called *peakrate*.  You are supposed to use this second one to limit the speed the first one can send it's bursts at.  Using this second one is optional, and if you don't use it the bursts are sent at device speed.

Finally, tbf has a *limit* parameter.  If the program persistently sends faster than *rate*, then packets will build up in the queue.  There isn't infinite kernel memory, so *limit* says how many bytes can build up before the kernel starts discarding packets.