# Can no longer ping containers after setting TBF qdisc on Docker0

Tags: networking, docker, tc, traffic-shaping

I am trying to use the `tc` command to manipulate traffic on the docker0 interface.

I run the commands

```
tc qdisc del dev docker0 root
tc qdisc add dev docker0 root handle 1: tbf rate 100mbps burst 1600 limit 1
```

I believe this is what it does:

- `tbf`: Specifies the TBF qdisc to be used.
- `rate 100mbps`: Sets the maximum bandwidth rate to 100 Mbps for the docker0 interface.
- `burst 1600`: Sets the maximum amount of data that can be transmitted in a single burst to 1600 bytes.
- `limit 1`: Limits the token bucket size to 1 token, which limits the amount of data that can be sent at any given time to the burst size.

However, after setting this rule, I can no longer ping containers that are already running and attached to the default docker0 interface. I can also no longer build images that contain commands such as `RUN apt-get update -y`.

Why is this the case. Can this qdisc configuration not be used alone?

Comment: `rate 100mbps` sets the rate to 100 megaBYTES per second (i.e. 800mbit), and `burst 1600` sets the burst rate to 1600 bits per second - that looks odd for a start, and `limit` specifies *the number of bytes that can be queued waiting for tokens to become available* - according to documentation

Comment: read the answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100785/bucket-size-in-tbf you may find it enlightening